# Wpf DataGrid with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to bind a WPF DataGrid to a EF7 DataContext and have it add, remove, update items when I edit them on the grid itself. So far I can insert and remove rows from the database using the grid. But I can't update items.

Here is the XAML for the DataGrid:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Data" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance models:Product}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Code"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Stock}" Header="Stock"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the C# code from the page:

```
public partial class ProductView
{
    private readonly Context context;
    private readonly BindingList<Product> products;
    public ProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new Context();
        products = new BindingList<Product>();
        foreach (var product in context.Products)
        {
            products.Add(product);
        }
        products.ListChanged += CollectionChanged;
        DataContext = products;
    }

    private void CollectionChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var product = products.ElementAt(e.NewIndex);
        switch (e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                context.Products.Add(product);
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                context.Products.Remove(product);
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemChanged:
                var oldProduct = context.Products.First(x => x.Id == product.Id);
                oldProduct.Code = product.Code;
                oldProduct.Name = product.Name;
                oldProduct.Price = product.Price;
                oldProduct.Stock = product.Stock;
                break;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am using ObservableCollections and INotifyPropertyChanged to do this.

Comment: Set a breakpoint here context.SaveChanges();  then tell us what you see.

Comment: Do the Product class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface correctly on all the properties you change?